# Offset image vertically in a ConstraintLayout from its center position

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I am centering an image on the screen as follows:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/dashboardConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" 
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I would like to do is have the image offset downward by 50dp from its center position. Adding a marginTop does not work. All that does is adds a margin at the top of the screen where the image is constrained. The image still remains in the center. But I want it shifted down by 50dp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried it and it works fine and I have highlighted the code that I have changed

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".Third">

         <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView //it is normar imageView in centered 
             android:id="@+id/logo"
             android:layout_width="155dp"
             android:layout_height="20dp"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
             app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

         <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView //in this imageView i used marginTop and it works perfectly
             android:id="@+id/logo1"
             android:layout_width="155dp"
             android:layout_height="20dp"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:src="@drawable/two"
             android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
             app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

         <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView //in this imageView i used vertical_bias and it work perfectly.
             android:id="@+id/logo2"
             android:layout_width="155dp"
             android:layout_height="20dp"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
             app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.60"  //there is 0.0=Top,  0.50=center,  1.0=Bottom and so on.
             app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output is:-

[image]